# Application request routing delete cache impossible when traffic on website

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, arr

Here is my problem.

My environment uses the ARR module (application request routing) in IIS because I have a server farm. On this farm house is a CMS that generates momentum on this same farm. The pages of my sites generated are cached by the ARR, and it's perfect like that.

By cons when an update is made on a site, the files in the cache must be destroyed. If at the time that the cache must be refreshed the site in question gets a lot of http requests, it is impossible to remove the files from the cache because IIS (ARR's) seems to keep a handle on the file.

Then I receive an error message stating that I did not have permission to delete the file. If I made ​​a IISReset files disappear. There are to me by a cons impossible to reset IIS on my server ARR, as several hundred sites through its ARR.

Actually I try to deleted the file VIA code, but if i try via explorer I get the same result.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Actually, the only way i can delete my arr cache file, with iis running, is remove the path from the cache drive, erease the file, and put back the drive in the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. I make a lot of test with some screen shot, call microsoft etc...

There is the good way to clean the cache [manually with ARR](https://serverfault.com/questions/360107/handle-lock-on-disk-cache-by-arr-module-how-release-it-without-recycle-the-appl)