# Handle lock on disk Cache by ARR Module. How release it without recycle the application pool?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, arr

> I get cached disk file in the directory c:\arrCache_media\video. IIS
>   still got an handle on the file, so i can't rename, delete or re-write
>   the file. But i can move the file to another folder, so I try this
>   avenue to solve my problem.

[image]

> I move my file entcadieux1.wmv.full in another folder a name Trash in
>   the path c:\Trash. When i move the file IIS still get the handle on
>   the file. If you look the screen shot of process monitor IIS now get
>   the file in the trash directory.

[image]

> If i delete the file, iis get the file in the system trash folder.

[image][image]

> My questions is, it's not normal that the ARR cache system lock the
>   file in the cache folder. I can open the file in read mode. So he 
>   could be logic that the handle on the file would be release after the
>   writing process. With this scenario i think the problem could be
>   solve. The file could be deleted manually, or by code, and iis will
>   send the request on the web farm server.
>   **I know if I recycle the application pool, iis will release the handle, but i dont won't to release the application pool because that will affect over 200 sites**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just potentially resolve my problem. After several hours of testing, code and all without success. What the tests show, the primary cache of ARR will keep a "lock" on the controller file to its existence. However the secondary cache is much more permissive (luckily) it allows us to deleted files without them it is "locked" by IIS. So what would say that I completely removed the primary cache on my servers ARR leaving only the secondary cache. So far the tests are successful.

Comment: So basically you configured only a secondary drive, no primary?